# Rails Unit Test Issue with rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rake

I am working on writing tests for a rails 2.3.4 application and I am running into the following error when I try to run the tests

`1) Failure:
default_test(ReportTest) [rake (0.8.7) lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:5]:
No tests were specified.`

This is what the only test file looks like:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include Authlogic::TestCase
  setup :activate_authlogic

  fixtures :users

  def setup
    @user = users(:one)
  end

  def test_user_is_valid
    assert @user.valid?
  end
end
```

One issue I could forsee being a problem is that I have multiple versions of rails installed and rake as well

```
rails (3.0.0, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 1.2.6)
rake (0.8.7, 0.8.3)
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: RVM dude. if you are going to have multiple versions of stuff there is no other way to roll.

Comment: I know man, I just got it installed tonight and need to set it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow the search for tests that `rake test` does has turned up a file named `_test.rb` which doesn't have a test in it. It will look through all the files under the test/units /functionals and /integration directories to try and locate tests.

I also once had the strange behaviour that a rails application in a sub directory of another rails application was finding more tests than it should have done as it was picking up tests from the 'parent' application. Might be worth checking that too.

Comment: That did it, had a bunch of unit test files and lots of em were just empty. Thanks.